# CSS Dynamic Resizing

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

**HTML:**

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <title> Dummy Site | Home</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./css/style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <div class="container">
            <div id="branding">
                <img src="https://i.imgur.com/MPoWmYb.png"></img>
                <h1>Title</h1>
                <h3>This is my description</h3>
            </div>

            <nav>
                <ul>
                    <li class="current"><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="page1.html">Page 1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="page2.html">Page 2</a></li>
                    <li><a href="page3.html">Page 3</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
    </header>  

    <section id="frontImage">
            <div class="frost">
                <h3></h3>
            </div>

    </section>

    <footer>
        <p>Name, 2018</p>
    </footer>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

**CSS:**

```
body{
    font:15px/1.5 Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    background-color:gray;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-size: cover;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    text-align: center;
}

/* Global */
.container{
    width: 80%;
    margin:auto;
    overflow:hidden;
}

ul{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}

/* Header and logo */
header{
    top:0;
    color:#ffffff;
    background: inherit;
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 200px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
}

header #branding{
    text-align: center;
}

header #branding h1{
    min-width: 200px;
    margin-left: 43.5%;
    margin-right: 43.5%;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    border: solid 4px #ffffff;
}

header #branding h3{
    margin-top:0;
}

header nav{
    text-align: center;
    margin-bottom: 10px;

}
header li{
    padding: 0 30px 0 30px;
    display: inline;
}

header li a{
    font-family: Verdana;
    font: bold;
    text-decoration: none;
    color:#ffffff;
}

header li:hover{
    border: 2px solid #ffffff;
}

header #branding img{
    border: solid 2px #ffffff;
    top:1%;
    left: 3%;
    width:130px;
    height:130px;
    position: absolute;
}

.frost{
    top: 16.5%;
    left:0;
    text-align: center;
    color:#ffffff;
    width:40em;
    height:47.65em;
    position:absolute;
    background: inherit;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: 0px auto;
    z-index: 1;
}

.frost:before{
      position: absolute;
      top: -20px;
      left: -70px;
      bottom: 0;
      z-index: 0;
      width: 200%;
      height: 200%;
      background-position: 50% 0;
      content: "";
      box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 3000px rgba(255,255,255,0.1);
      filter: blur(25px);
      z-index: -1;
      }

footer{
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    height:4.55em;
    width: 100%;
    color:#ffffff;
    text-align: center;
    background: inherit;
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 200px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
}
```

**Codepen example:** https://codepen.io/anon/pen/dQeeRG

Hi all,

I'm currently building a website, however I can't seem to get it to resize dynamically with the browser window (Chrome).

I've tried using positioning as well as having a container set to 80% and margins on the elements etc. but things like the logo don't resize and the "frost" element doesn't adjust whatsoever.

I'm trying to do this without Javascript for the time being as I'm learning that on the side.

Just to note, function of .frost is just to display a frosted glass effect.

Any advice/suggestions are welcome.

Comment: You opened `<header>` then opened  `<div class="container">` then you closed `<header>` and in the end you closed `<div class="container">`, You should fix this, open `<div class="container">` first.

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear to me what do you want to get exactly, but the problem of this layout is the absolute width of the class `.frost`, i.e. 40em. Delete it or change it to 100% and then you get a responsive layout.